# Invoke bean validation

Tags: jsf-2, hibernate-validator

I am using JSF 2 ,myfaces, hibernate-validator-4.1.0.Final.jar.

I use hibernate-validator for validating values entered in form.

```
public class Client {
   @Persistent
   @Pattern(regexp = "|.+@.+\\.[a-z]+", message = "Email format is invalid.")
   private String email;
   //getter
}
```

I am developing bulk-upload module ,where i parse csv data and create database records.

```
...
try{
  Client cl=new Client();
  cl.setEmail("from_csv_data");
}catch( //validation failed
```

How do i reuse the same validator here?

---

Set> constraintViolations =  validator.validate(nc);
throws this exception

```
SEVERE: Received 'java.lang.NoSuchMethodError' when invoking action listener '#{clientBean.bulkUpload}' for component 'j_idt86'
```

Jan 28, 2011 8:35:39 AM javax.faces.event.MethodExpressionActionListener processAction
    SEVERE: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: javax.persistence.Persistence.getPersistenceUtil()Ljavax/persistence/PersistenceUtil;
    at 
   org.hibernate.validator.engine.resolver.JPATraversableResolver.isReachable(JPATraversableResolver.java:62)

I tried this solution [link](https://forum.hibernate.org/viewtopic.php?f=9&t=1002745)
I have hibernate-jpa-2.0-api-1.0.0.Final.jar,hibernate-validator-4.1.0.Final.jar
Do I need any other jar to make this work?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can invoke the validator manually with something like:

```
ValidatorFactory factory = Validation.buildDefaultValidatorFactory();

Validator validator = factory.getValidator();

Client client = new Client();

Set<ConstraintViolation<Client>> constraintViolations = validator.validate(client);
```

Answer (score 1):

You most likely have another incomplete JPA 2 jar file on the classpath. Unfortunately, some incomplete versions of this jar got released at some stage (TopLink for example). Check your classpath for any jar containing JPA classes. See also https://forum.hibernate.org/viewtopic.php?f=9&t=999855

Comment: Thanks,I removed hibernate-jpa-2.0-api-1.0.0.Final.jar and now its working/validating